# Update Existing Feature Class by Replacing Features with Updated Versions from a Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, update, archiving

I have a feature class in a versioned ArcSDE geodatabase with archiving enabled. I receive regular updates for this data in shapefile format. I want to be able to replace any features that have changed with the new version from the shapefile. How can I do that without recreating the feature class and thus losing my archived history?

I have gotten as far as identifying which features have changed, been added, or been deleted. But how to I select all of the features in the existing feature class that have the same ID as the changed/deleted features in the updated data and replace them with the updated features?

Comment: There is an Update geoprocessing tool but I think a model would work better in this case. Is there a matching field between the shapefile and SDE?

Comment: Yes, they share almost all the same fields. I am planning to use the name field. So, if the name in the existing feature class matches that of a changed feature in the shapfile, delete it. And then append all of the changed features into the existing feature class.

Comment: It's not complicated but I do suggest to do it on a file geodatabase copy of the SDE data. Do a join SDE-Shapefile (keep common) and use delete_management, then just append... all done! **warning** delete_management will happily remove all the features in your database and give you a warning while it's erasing your valuable data if you get the join wrong!